# Loading variables from a text file into bash script

Tags: bash

Is it possible to load new lines from a text file to variables in bash?

Text file looks like?

```
EXAMPLEfoo 
EXAMPLEbar
EXAMPLE1
EXAMPLE2
EXAMPLE3
EXAMPLE4
```

Variables become

```
$1 = EXAMPLEfoo 
$2 = EXAMPLEbar
```

ans so on?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
$ s=$(<file)
$ set -- $s
$ echo $1
EXAMPLEfoo
$ echo $2
EXAMPLEbar
$ echo $@
EXAMPLEfoo EXAMPLEbar EXAMPLE1 EXAMPLE2 EXAMPLE3 EXAMPLE4
```

I would improve the above by getting rid of temporary variable s:

```
$ set -- $(<file)
```

And if you have as input a file like this

```
variable1 = value
variable2 = value
```

You can use following construct to get named variables.

```
input=`cat filename|grep -v "^#"|grep "\c"`
set -- $input

while [ $1 ]
 do
  eval $1=$3
  shift 3
 done
```

Answer (score 4):

```
cat somefile.txt| xargs bash_command.sh
```

bash_command.sh will receive these lines as arguments

Answer (score 3):

```
saveIFS="$IFS"
IFS=$'\n'
array=($(<file))
IFS="$saveIFS"
echo ${array[0]}    # output: EXAMPLEfoo 
echo ${array[1]}    # output: EXAMPLEbar
for i in "${array[@]}"; do echo "$i"; done    # iterate over the array
```

**Edit:**

The loop in your pastebin has a few problems. Here it is as you've posted it:

```
for i in "${array[@]}"; do echo "  "AD"$count = "$i""; $((count=count+1)); done
```

Here it is as it should be:

```
for i in "${array[@]}"; do declare AD$count="$i"; ((count=count+1)); done
```

or

```
for i in "${array[@]}"; do declare AD$count="$i"; ((count++)); done
```

But why not use the array directly? You could call it AD instead of array and instead of accessing a variable called "AD4" you'd access an array element "${AD[4]}".

```
echo "${AD[4]}"
if [[ ${AD[9]} == "EXAMPLE value" ]]; then do_something; fi
```

Comment: Would I be asking for a world of pain to try define the variables in the loop? Like this http://pastebin.com/MqGiS8WK

Answer (score 1):

This can be done be with an array if you don't require these variables as inputs to a script. `push()` function lifted from the [Advanced Scripting Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/arrays.html)

```
push()            # Push item on stack.
{
if [ -z "$1" ]    # Nothing to push?
then
  return
fi

let "SP += 1"     # Bump stack pointer.
stack[$SP]=$1

return
}
```

The contents of `/tmp/test`

```
[root@x~]# cat /tmp/test
EXAMPLEfoo
EXAMPLEbar
EXAMPLE1
EXAMPLE2
EXAMPLE3
EXAMPLE4

SP=0; for  i in `cat /tmp/test`; do push $i ; done
```

Then

```
[root@x~]# echo ${stack[3]}
EXAMPLE1
```

Answer (score 1):

None of the above will work, if your values are quoted with spaces.

However, not everythinf is lost.

Try this:

```
eval "$(VBoxManage showvminfo "$VMname" --details --machinereadable | egrep "^(name|UUID|CfgFile|VMState)")"
echo "$name {$UUID} $VMState ($VMStateChangeTime) CfgFile=$CfgFile"
```

P.S.
Nothing will ever work, if your names are quoted or contain dashes.
If you have something like that, as is the case with VBoxManage output ("IDE-1-0"="emptydrive" and so on), either `egrep` only specific values, as shown in my example, or silence the errors.

However, silencing erors is always dangerous. You never know, when the next value will have unquoted "*" in it, thus you must treat values loaded this way very careful, with all due precaution.