# how to control copying files based on another file in Unix?

Tags: unix

I have a script as below which copies files from Source directory to Target directory based on existance of file based on file number

---

```
#! /bin/ksh

export SRCDIR=/informat/PowerCenter/9.1.0/server/infa_shared/SrcFiles/CSI/historical

export BINDIR=/informat/PowerCenter/9.1.0/server/infa_shared/Bin

export TGTDIR=/informat/PowerCenter/9.1.0/server/infa_shared/SrcFiles/CSI/incoming


export LASTRUNDT=`cat /informat/PowerCenter/9.1.0/server/infa_shared/ParameterFiles/CSI_CONFIRMIT_RESPONSE.param | grep '\$\$LASTRUNDATE=' | sed 's/\$\$LASTRUNDATE=//g'`

export FILEDT=`date -d "$LASTRUNDT +1day" +%-m_%-d_%Y`


for FILE_NUM in {11259,11318,11366,11367,11368,11369,11370,11372,11373,11374,11385,11386,11387,11388,11389,11390,11398};do

  export GET_FNAMES=AllResponses_${FILE_NUM}_${FILEDT}*.txt

         GET_FNAME=`ls -1 ${GET_FNAMES}`
         if [ -f ${GET_FNAME} ]; then
         cp ${SRCDIR}/${GET_FNAME} ${TGTDIR}
        fi
done
```

---

But while doing above file copy with above script, **i dont want to copy files whose file numbers present in below file.**

```
CSI_CONFIRMIT_RESPONSE_SWITCHOFF.cfg

11369

11370

11372
```

Please help me. Thanks

Comment: You've used a snippet posted in an answer to your previous [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19583890/how-to-read-a-variable-from-a-file-to-a-unix-script-in-unix).  If that code snippet was worth using, why not upvote the answer or mark it accepted?

Comment: Friend..i didn't get you...My point is i am accepting answers from you all otherwise how can i post my questions here. Sorry if i mislead you. If you are able, please answer to this latest question. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to use `grep` to check if the file number is present in the file and only perform the copy if it isn't:

```
for FILE_NUM in 11259 11318 11366 11367 11368 11369 11370 11372 11373 11374 11385 11386 11387 11388 11389 11390 11398; do
    if ! grep -qFxw "$FILE_NUM" CSI_CONFIRMIT_RESPONSE_SWITCHOFF.cfg
    then
        # copy code here
    fi
done
```

However, this is not efficient because you are running `grep` for each number.

A more efficient way, is to use `comm` once to compare your number list against the file in order to work out which numbers are not present in the file. This is shown below:

```
file_nums=(11259 11318 11366 11367 11368 11369 11370 11372 11373 11374 11385 11386 11387 11388 11389 11390 11398)
comm -23 <(printf -- '%s\n' "${file_nums[@]}" | sort) <(sort CSI_CONFIRMIT_RESPONSE_SWITCHOFF.cfg) | while IFS= read -r FILE_NUM
do
    # copy code here
done
```